# Connect to my hidden wifi which I know the password and the ssid name

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I'm using kali linux and I want to connect to my hidden wifi

so I know my SSID name and the password, how can I connect to this wifi?

Comment: Since you're running Kali I assume you understand why hiding your SSID is a really bad idea.

Comment: I have desktop and two smartphone, and my pc work with kali linux and windows 10, so I'm not alone

Answer (score 2):

Create a wpa_supplicant configuration file with the following content:

```
#nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-Hidden.conf

update_config=1
ap_scan=1
network={
       ssid="YOUR-HIDDEN-SSID"
       scan_ssid=1
       #psk="YOURPASSWORD"
       psk=..........................
}
```

Then connect:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-Hidden.conf -B
```

Replace `wlan0` with your wifi interface.

**Step by step**:

to create the `wpa_supplicant-Hidden.conf` file:

```
touch /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-Hidden.conf 
wpa_passphrase "YOUR-HIDDEN-SSID" YOUR-PASSWORD > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-Hidden.conf
```

Then edit your `wpa_supplicant-Hidden.conf` by adding the missing parametre as described bellow.

A sample script to connect:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall wpa_supplicant
echo "starting wpa_supplicant"
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-Hidden.conf -B
echo "getting IP through dhcp"
dhclient wlan0
echo "ping test for 5 seconds"
ping -w 5  8.8.8.8
```

If you have Network-Manager installed the `killall wpa_supplicant` will kill the runing `wpa_supplicant`service.

To get what is the SSID you are currently connect to , run the following:

```
iwgetid
```

sample output:

```
wlan0    ESSID:"YOUR-HIDDEN-SSID"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you are using the default `kali` desktop environment, `gnome`:

1. Open the system menu from the right side of the top bar.
2. Select `Wi-Fi Not Connected`. The Wi-Fi section of the menu will expand.
3. Click Wi-Fi Settings.
4. Click the `Connect to Hidden Network…` button.
5. In the window that appears, select a previously-connected hidden network using the Connection drop-down list, or `New` for a new one.
6. For a new connection, type the network name and choose the type of wireless security from the Wi-Fi security drop-down list.
7. Enter the password or other security details.
8. Click Connect.